# Finding only the parent DIV's and then child DIV's within the parents with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Give the following HTML;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DIV Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Hello 1</h1>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello 1</h1>
    </div>
        <div>
        <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    </div>      
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello 1</h1>
    </div>
        <div>
        <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    </div>      
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Hello 3</h1>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello 1</h1>
    </div>
        <div>
        <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    </div>      
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Hello 4</h1>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello 1</h1>
    </div>
        <div>
        <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    </div>      
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Hello 5</h1>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello 1</h1>
    </div>
        <div>
        <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    </div>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How would I use Vanilla JS to return only the parent divs? For example, using the code `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");` at the moment it will return 15 div's, what code could I use to return only the parent div's which would be 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the top level divs with `document.querySelectorAll('body > div')`

For example, `document.querySelectorAll('body > div').length` to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll("body > div");